# Поиск идиомы со значением "близко к друг другу", "телом к телу", в идеале с намёком на половую связь

Tags: выражения

В песне группы Faun "Tanz mit mir" поётся:

> Ich schenk' dir ein nur wenn du tanzt mit mir,
>
> Wenn du tanzt mit mir, und zwar jetzt und hier
>
> Ich schenk' dir ein nur wenn du tanzt mit mir,
>
> Ich will tanzen **Leib an Leib**

Наиболее близкий перевод слова Leib, который я смог найти -- "тело", то есть, "Leib an Leib" значит буквально что-то вроде "тело к телу". Значение последней строчки в этом четверостишии -- "Я хочу танцевать близко друг к другу". В песне делаются прямые указания на возможную половую связь героев, например "Und später Schöne teil das Bett mit mir" ("А потом, красавица, раздели со мной постель").

Выражение “плечом к плечу” имеет коннотацию борьбы с чем-то, повернувшись, всё-таки, друг от друга. “Спина к спине”, пожалуй, ещё хуже подходит.

Хотелось бы найти выражение, максимально подходящее по контексту. Оно должно означать "близко друг к другу", в идеале упоминать какие-то части тела.

Comment: тушка к тушке!!!

Comment: @shabunc Кстати, могло бы подойти, если задать всему переводу соответствующий тон.

Comment: Щекой к щеке? Прижавшись друг к другу? Тело к телу, кстати, тоже неплохо звучит,  хоть и неидеоматично. А нужна ли идиоматичность?

Comment: _Хочу слиться я в танце с тобой._

Comment: "Я свежа, как дыханье левкоя, О, сплетем же истомности тел!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможно, вам подойдут следующие выражения:

Приникнув к друг другу, прильнув к друг другу, слившись воедино, в одно целое.
Слившись воедино в танце.

Comment: Если в течение 24 часов не будет предложений лучше, приму Ваш ответ! Спасибо большое.

Comment: " Ах обмануть меня нетрудно..."(Пушкин А.С.)

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется,

> Прижавшись грудью к твоей груди

несет достаточно сексуального подтекста и довольно точно описывает танец в тесном контакте.

Answer (score 1):

"Плоть к плоти", "Станцуем к плоти плоть", и т. д. И намек на "плотское" явный присутствует.